# Laravel 4 Method Improvement

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have this index method:

```
public function index()
{
    // In the view, there are several multiselect boxes (account managers, company names and account types). This code retrives the values from the POST method of the form/session.
    $company_names_value = Input::get('company_names_value');
    $account_managers_value = Input::get('account_managers_value');
    $account_types_value = Input::get('account_types_value');

    // If there has been no form submission, check if the values are empty and if they are assign a default.
    // Essentially, all of the records in the table column required.
    if (is_null($company_names_value))
    {
        $company_names_value = DB::table('accounts')
            ->orderBy('company_name')
            ->lists('company_name');
    }

    if (is_null($account_managers_value))
    {    
        $account_managers_value = DB::table('users')
            ->orderBy(DB::raw('CONCAT(first_name," ",last_name)'))
            ->select(DB::raw('CONCAT(first_name," ",last_name) as amname'))
            ->lists('amname');
    }

    if (is_null($account_types_value))
    {
        $account_types_value = DB::table('account_types')
            ->orderBy('type')
            ->lists('type');
    }

    // In the view, there is a dropdown box, that allows the user to select the amount of records to show per page. Retrieve that value or set a default.
    $perPage = Input::get('perPage', 10);

    // This code retrieves the order from the session that has been selected by the user by clicking on a table column title. The value is placed in the session via the getOrder() method and is used later in the Eloquent query and joins.
    $order = Session::get('account.order', 'company_name.asc');
    $order = explode('.', $order);

    // Here we perform the joins required and order the records, then select everything from accounts and select their id's as aid. Then whereIn is used to select records where company name, account manager name and account type matches the values of the multiselect boxes or the default set above.
    $accounts_query = Account::leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'accounts.user_id')
        ->leftJoin('account_types', 'account_types.id', '=', 'accounts.account_type_id')
        ->orderBy($order[0], $order[1])
        ->select(array('accounts.*', DB::raw('accounts.id as aid')));

    if (!empty($company_names_value)) $accounts_query = $accounts_query->whereIn('accounts.company_name', $company_names_value);

    $accounts = $accounts_query->whereIn(DB::raw('CONCAT(users.first_name," ",users.last_name)'), $account_managers_value)
        ->whereIn('account_types.type', $account_types_value)
        ->paginate($perPage)->appends(array('company_names_value' => Input::get('company_names_value'), 'account_managers_value' => Input::get('account_managers_value'), 'account_types_value' => Input::get('account_types_value')));

    $accounts_trash = Account::onlyTrashed()
        ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'accounts.user_id')
        ->leftJoin('account_types', 'account_types.id', '=', 'accounts.account_type_id')
        ->orderBy($order[0], $order[1])
        ->select(array('accounts.*', DB::raw('accounts.id as aid')))
        ->get();

    $message = Session::get('message');

    $default = ($perPage === null ? 10 : $perPage);

    $this->layout->content = View::make('admin.accounts.index', array(
        'accounts'          => $accounts,
        'accounts_trash'    => $accounts_trash,
        'company_names'     => DB::table('accounts')->orderBy('company_name')->lists('company_name', 'company_name'),
        'account_managers'  => DB::table('users')->orderBy(DB::raw('CONCAT(first_name," ",last_name)'))->select(DB::raw('CONCAT(first_name," ",last_name) as amname'))->lists('amname', 'amname'),
        'account_types'     => DB::table('account_types')->orderBy('type')->lists('type', 'type'),
        'perPage'           => $perPage,
        'message'           => $message,
        'default'           => $default
    ));
}
```

Basically, I am building a query that searches several tables (hence the joins). In the view a user has the ability to select multiple values from various multi-select boxes and then submit a form which will then populate the $company_names_value, $account_managers_value and $account_types_value variables.

Initially, when there is no form submission, I'm using Query Builder to select all records for each type, and then using them in the query.

It works but it is slow and messy. I was wondering if any of you Laravel 4 gurus could help me improve it further, so that the queries are faster and the code is lighter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Holy balls! fix your indentation

Comment: @afarazit What's up with the indentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has now been refactored significantly, and it is very fast now. I've moved most of my code in to my models, as well as refactoring that code.

Here's the new index method:

```
public function index()
{
    $account = explode(',', Input::get('account'));
    $account_manager = explode(',', Input::get('account_manager'));
    $account_type = explode(',', Input::get('account_type'));

    $perPage = Input::get('perPage', 10);

    $order = Session::get('account.order', 'company_name.asc');
    $order = explode('.', $order);

    $accounts = Account::accounts($order, $account, $account_manager, $account_type)->paginate($perPage)->appends(array(
        'account'           => Input::get('account'),
        'account_manager'   => Input::get('account_manager'),
        'account_type'      => Input::get('account_type'),
        'perPage'           => Input::get('perPage')
    ));

    $accounts_trash = Account::accountsTrash($order)->get();

    $message = Session::get('message');

    $default = ($perPage === null ? 10 : $perPage);

    $this->layout->content = View::make('admin.accounts.index', compact('accounts', 'accounts_trash', 'message', 'default'));
}
```

And the new getAccountByName() method in my controller that is used during my AJAX call. This should probably go in the model:

```
public function getAccountByName()
{
    $name = Input::get('account');
    return Account::select(array('id', DB::raw('company_name as text')))->where('company_name', 'like', "%$name%")->get();
}
```

And finally two new methods in my model for retrieving accounts and accounts trash:

```
public function scopeAccounts($query, $order, $account, $account_manager, $account_type)
{
    $query->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'accounts.user_id')
        ->leftJoin('account_types', 'account_types.id', '=', 'accounts.account_type_id')
        ->orderBy($order[0], $order[1])
        ->select(array('accounts.*', DB::raw('accounts.id as aid')));

    if (!empty($account[0])) {
       $query = $query->whereIn('accounts.id', $account);
    }
    if (!empty($account_manager[0])) {
       $query = $query->whereIn('users.id', $account_manager);
    }
    if (!empty($account_type[0])) {
       $query = $query->whereIn('account_types.id', $account_type);
    }
}

public function scopeAccountsTrash($query, $order)
{
    $query->onlyTrashed()
        ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'accounts.user_id')
        ->leftJoin('account_types', 'account_types.id', '=', 'accounts.account_type_id')
        ->orderBy($order[0], $order[1])
        ->select(array('accounts.*', DB::raw('accounts.id as aid')));
}
```

Again, there's probably a ton of things to get tidied up here but I'm certainly closer to a much faster and cleaner solution. Doing it like this has reduced the loading times from 12 seconds to 234ms.